# Am I allowed to do this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$.

We know $\exists A$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - Ah}{h} = 0$.

Given this assumption, can we split this into $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) }{h} - \lim\limits_{h\to0^+} \frac{Ah}{h} = 0$.

Is this breaking any rules?

Comment: This is fine as long as you don't confuse $h$ and $x$. ;-)

Comment: Why is the result equal to $0$?

Comment: We are to assume it is equal to 0.

Comment: I´m asking since $\lim\limits_{h\to0^+} \frac{Ah}{h}=A$

Comment: @callculus I see, thank you. Is it true that the **only way** that this limit can equal 0 is if $\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = A$?

Comment: @Zexion12 Yes, that´s true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

$$\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - Ah}{h} = 0$$

and yes we are allowed if the limit

$$\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = A$$

exists finite.

Comment: If we don't know it exists, then we can't do it?

Comment: @Zexion12 If $A$ is a constant, it is the definition of right derivative and $f'_+(a)=A$.

Comment: Is it true that the **only way** that this limit can equal 0 is if $\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = A$?

Comment: @Zexion12 If $A$ is a number then it always holds and by definition $f'_+(a)=A$ otherwise it is not true in general.